# is on keyboard one side alt is more prominent than other side while using them in shortcut keys

Tags: windows, button, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

for instances,

1. using my laptop keyboard in vs code,whenver i try to use alt the mouse click on certain line to make multi line cursors, i notice that multi line cursors is only implemented when i use left alt button not with right alt button
2. when using left alt + f4 i can use it for shutdown,restart, etc purposes but right alt + f4 doesnot serve this purpose,

is this normal ?

i tried to search this online but i am not getting any answer for this, and i am curious about this so anyone can help me in understanding this